# Blade Form without action or url

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How to generate a form by Blade template engine without generating `action` attribute? 
I would like to generate a form just for ajax request.

Comment: If you use ajax so why it is matter? the form not really submit to the url that in the action attribute.

Comment: I know that. But I would like to know is there any way to do this. Its about flexibility what Laravel gives.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's actually not possible to tell the Form builder to omit the action attribute. Some attributes will be set in any case, and the `action`-attribute is one of them. Here's the relevant part from the function:

```
public function open(array $options = array())
{
    //....

    $attributes['method'] = $this->getMethod($method);
    $attributes['action'] = $this->getAction($options);
    $attributes['accept-charset'] = 'UTF-8';

    //....

    return '<form'.$attributes.'>'.$append;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/master/FormBuilder.php#L104

But you can easily overwrite it by just passing in a 'url':

```
Form::open(['url' => '#'])
```

*Note:* Overwriting the `action` like `Form::open(['action' => '#'])` would throw an error because this specifies the name of a route. `url` specifies the raw url.

Comment: Last few sentences of this answer is actually the correct answer. instead of action/route use URL and the job is done.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you dont want the form to submit

```
{{ Form::open(['onsubmit' => 'return false']) }}
```

2) If you have a ajax function, you can call it like so

```
{{ Form::open(['onsubmit' => 'yourAjaxFunction(); return false']) }}
```

3) If you want to include Angular JS directive to the form

```
{{ Form::open(['ng-submit' => 'submit()', 'onsubmit' => 'return false']) }}
```